Serving two Docker containers with SSL using Nginx
EDIT: I forgot to mention that both flutter.example.com and nodejs.example.com need to be available externally- as a website and api service for a mobile app respectively.
Edit 2: I feel a bit silly, so I'll go read on reverse proxies. Thank you.
I have a Ubuntu20:04LTE VM on Azure. I have two containers, one running Flutter webapp flutter, and the other running a NodeJs server api, both of them have SSL certificates installed on the host machine using Certbot. Both containers are under the same default docker network called bridge.
Let's say both containers can be accessed through the following url(s):
flutter.example.com with local ip address 172.17.0.4 on port 5556
nodejs.example.com with local ip address 172.17.0.2 on port 5000
I want my flutter container to consume an endpoint from api locally through the host network without having to use https://nodejs.example.com/example/endpoint .
when I sh into my flutter container and execute:
curl http://172.17.0.5:5555/status
I get a response from the api container, however when I execute the same command with https instead of http, I get the following error:
OpenSSL/3.3.1: error:0A0000C6:SSL routines::packet length too long
Here are my Nginx conf file for flutter
server {
  server_name flutter.example.com;

     #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5556; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        #stub_status on;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/flutter.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/flutter.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = flutter.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name flutter.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

Here is my Nginx conf files for api
server {
    server_name  nodejs.example.com;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        #stub_status on;
    }

    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = nodejs.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen       80;
    server_name  nodejs.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


I have googled this particular issue and can't seem to make it work.. do the requests need to be through the domain name? Does this mean that they are already communicating locally because I have Nginx? What am I missing, I am lost.


when I sh into my flutter container and execute:
curl http://172.17.0.5:5555/status
I get a response from the api container, however when I execute the same command with https instead of http, I get the following error:
OpenSSL/3.3.1: error:0A0000C6:SSL routines::packet length too long


https and http use different ports. Furthermore, 5555 is not nginx, but direct access to your backend. It appears you've configured nginx as a reverse proxy, in which case you will have to use hostnames; e.g. https://nodejs.example.com/foo/bar as URL.
If you want things to only be accessible locally, there's no point in using nginx as reverse proxy, nor any point in using https.

Thank you for replying, I forgot to mention that both of my containers need to be accessible externally, as my api container is also being used for a mobile app and the flutter container also needs to available externally as it will serve as a cms.

Sure, your setup covers that.

So.. does this mean when flutter calls the api, it has to through itshttps:// domain name? If that is the case, is the traffic between the two containers considered local?

It's local anyway. But if you access it directly, you don't need domain name. If you go through your reverse proxy, you need the name and https yes. I think you should spend some time reading about reverse proxies, because it appears you've followed a tutorial you didn't entirely understand.

Thank you for answering. I definitely need to do that

Look at it this way: You have two local web servers on different ports. They don't care about names, only ports. In addition you have nginx, listening for https traffic on the standard port (443). It needs the name to differentiate traffic. Locally you can access things both ways.
